# Can't get value from service class

Tags: angular

`component.ts` file:

```ts
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { HistoryService } from '../../../../shared/history.service';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { History } from '../../../../shared/history.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ins-history',
  templateUrl: './ins-history.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ins-history.component.css'],
  providers:[HistoryService]
})

export class InsHistoryComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public UserProfileService: HistoryService, private router: Router) { }


  ngOnInit() {

    this.HistoryList();
  }

  HistoryList()
  { let title = this.UserProfileService.Title;
      console.log(title);
      this.UserProfileService.getHistoryList(title).subscribe((res)=> {
      this.UserProfileService.history= res as History[];
      alert('ok');

    });
  }
```

The two `console.log`s inside the `getEmail` function in `history.service.ts` work properly but the `console.log` in `HistoryList` function return `undefined`. Why is that happening?

[image: history.service.ts]

Comment: `Title: string`; is just declared with a type string in your service but doesn't get assigned since `this.UserProfileService.getEmail('title string value to be passed here')` which does the assignment for `this.Title = title` is never called in your component, hence undefined, in short your `getEmail(title: string) {}` method in service doesn't get any value, you need to pass some value to it! the `title` value can be for an example some hardcoded string or you get from query params or from another service or from your template through some events or ngModel, but it has to get some value!

Comment: I am passing value to getEmail function using  another component it works properly but when a call this.UserProfileService.Title in console.log it return  undefine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a wrong way to do this you can use this to assign value to a variable in a service.

```
this.UserProfileService.Title=someValue;
```

Comment: oooooo you should use keyword static before Title in your service.

     static Title:string;

Comment: thanks but then how to access that Title from component.ts .this.UserProfileService.Title is not working

Comment: You must directly call the Title from your service. Like this:    HistoryService.Title

Comment: Or you can save your title in a sessionStorage and use it everywhere in your project

Answer (score 0):

UserProfileService.getEmail() never gets called in HistoryList(), that's why UserProfileService.title is undefined when you log it.

Comment: i am try to assign title  to string Title and call it inside HistoryList